# Static contraction training: is working out for 25 seconds once a month enough to build muscle?

Tags: physiology

According to conventional wisdom, in order to get results in a timely manner, one should train multiple days a week lifting weights for several sets of 1–5 reps for strength and 6–12 reps for hypertrophy (muscle growth).

Pete Sisco, author of multiple weightlifting books and e-books, says "…Many people can train productively lifting weights only once per month."

> Sisco claims his training takes only 1% to 2% of the time of conventional strength training.
>
> …
>
> On his GetThisStrong.com website a video clip shows the 49-year-old Sisco leg pressing a Toyota. Sisco claims his 16-year-old son, who also lifts the automobile, got strong enough to perform the feat in only 45 seconds of training time.
>
> …
>
> According to Sisco, "If you want to get strong the trump card is to lift a heavier weight for a very brief period rather than lift a lighter weight many times using multiple repetitions and several sets of repetitions as most people do. Static Contraction training shows people how to lift the heaviest weight they can in only their strongest and safest range of motion but to hold the weight statically for only five seconds."
>
> …
>
> Sisco's static contraction training routines typically address only five muscle groups per workout and with just five seconds of effort for each one his workouts are brief , to say the least. Also, this training is not nearly as frequent. [Sisco says] "Almost everyone can afford time for 25 seconds of exercise once a month"
>
> https://www.prweb.com/releases/2008/08/prweb1248534.htm

Is it true that anyone can get super strong by lifting very heavy weights for very brief durations as infrequently as once per month?

Comment: I think you are getting downvotes and flags because, between your handle and the subject matter, this looks like spam. Looking at your contributions across the network, this seems unlikely. Is there a way we can edit this to make it seem less spammy?

Comment: Upvoted. Seems like a legitimate question to me.

Comment: This might be better suited for the Physical Fitness site.

Comment: It's a legit question for this site... and I suspect the Physical Fitness site would handle it differently.  I strongly suspect that the answer is "No.  That's BS", but that's the sort of question you're *supposed* to ask here.

Comment: though... it might not be notable.  As far as I can tell, this guy has a *lot* of pay-for hype going on, but might not actually have anything underneath it.

Comment: I'll note that what he appears to be describing is a form of "isometric exercise", a technique that has been around for decades, and which is presumably well-researched.

Comment: The claim in the title differs from the one in the body. Are you skeptical about the effectiveness of static contraction training or do you want an answer specifically addressing the claim about the effectiveness of doing it 25 seconds a month?

Comment: One kind of gets the impression that the "25 seconds a month" claim is for a given muscle group, with many different muscle groups being exercised in a single session, and that this number is referring to several 5-10 second exercises of that group.  And that the reference may be to *maintaining* strength vs *gaining* strength -- ie, a "maintenance" protocol rather than one for "training".

Answer (score 3):

An [article](https://www.brianmac.co.uk/articles/scni36a3.htm) purportedly written by Sisco states:

> Also related to the intensity/duration principle is the principle of
>   workout frequency. As the intensity of your workouts increases, your
>   body will require more time to recover, and that is why the frequency
>   of workouts is dramatically decreased in the Static Contraction
>   Training routine. **For the first six or so workouts, you should be
>   working out no more than 2 times per week, and then after that, you
>   should be switching to once per week, assuming you are working out at
>   the proper intensity level.** This is a must on this workout as your
>   body must be given adequate time to recover AND grow between workouts.

Another [article](https://www.precisiontraining.com/Static_Contraction_Get_Maximum_Gains_Using_a_Minimum_Dosage.html) by Sisco:

> We recruited some hardcore bodybuilders who had already developed
>   impressive physiques…so it would be extra challenging to put new
>   muscle on these subjects compared to average subjects. **We put them on
>   a routine averaging just 2.1 workouts per week** where they statically
>   held heavy weights (without any up and down movement) in their
>   strongest range, but without being “locked out”.

Sisco appears to be very inconsistent in his advice.